# Thermodynamics compression work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

So I have a college homework problem that I have not been able to solve

"A 4-L rigid rank contains 2 kg of saturated liquid-vapor mixture of water at 50 degrees celsius. The water is now slowly heated until it exists in a single phase. At the final state, will the water be in the liquid phase or the vapor phase? What will your answer be if the volume of the tank were 10L instead of 4L?"

In this problem, I did not understand how to find the pressure from the water vapor, the mass of the water vapor, and the volume occupied by the liquid water. I also do not understand the relationship between saturation pressure and temperature.

I have tried my lecture notes, googling, khanacademy, and other questions on the physics stack exchange but I can't quite understand how to apply the topics mentioned to this problem. Could someone give me some insight on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you learned how to use the Saturated Steam Tables in your course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the mass and volume are constant, the specific volume is constant. In the first case it is 0.002 m³/kg (0.004/2), in the second case it's 0.005 m³/kg.

[image: T-v diagram for water]

The region under the curve in the T-v diagram is the vapor+liquid region. The region to the left is the liquid region, to the right is the vapor region. The state of the system in case one is somewhere on the vertical line corresponding to a specific volume of 0.002 m³/kg. Heating the system will move that point upward, but it will remain on that vertical line. That line crosses the curve to the left of the critical point, in other words, it crosses the **saturated liquid line**. The vertical line representing a specific volume of 0.005 m³/kg crosses the curve to the right of the critical point: it crosses the **saturated vapor line**. So the answer in case one (4 liter tank) is liquid phase, in case two (10 liter tank) the answer is vapor phase.